# Owl Carousel - Navigation Buttons move all sliders in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have multiple Owl Carouse sliders in a page. The problem is that when I use the control button from one slider it moves all the sliders in the page.

I initialize the sliders based on a unique id using this function

```
function property_slider_v2(slider_id){   
    console.log('we do '+slider_id);
    jQuery('#'+slider_id).owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        nav:true,
        items:6,
        dots:false,
        mouseDrag:true,
        video:true,
        autoHeight: true,
        autoWidth:true,
        stagePadding:0,
       // rtl:true,
        navText : [
            '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>',
            '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>'
        ],
    });
  
}
```

the html markup looks like this (page is in php)

```
$slider_id='property_slider_carousel_elementor_v2_'.rand(1,99999);
.....
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme " id="'.$slider_id.'" data-auto="">
......
</div>

print'<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        property_slider_v2("'.$slider_id.'");
      });
    //]]>
</script>';
```

Beside the "one button controls all" issue all the sliders works as they should.

Comment: $slider_id always the same for all carousels. Mistake in the logic. For ex. you generate id 4416 then you print script that enable carousel #4416 and it seems that all carousels has id 4416. You need generate individual id for each carousel. And individual init for each carousel.

Comment: I think i did not explain correctly   . I print html for 4416 then i trigger owl for 4416, after i print html for 5555 and trigger owl for 5555  and so own. The js function is at the end of each html markup - so 5 ids,-> 5 markups ,each followed by the js function. Also i triple checked this looking into view source and i call the js function with a unique id - also checked by the console.log in function.  Thank you

Comment: Just a typo - i fixed that. The real code use property_slider_v2 on both places . Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: So it's look like everything is correct. I see "elementor" name in the code. Is it wordpress plugin? I worked with this plugin. There is an assumption - Elementor can init carousel in parallel with your script. And may be there is problem with nav btns. Can you check in the source code if there any calls: (".owl-carousel").owlCarousel on the page?

Comment: I mean, the elementor can call general initialization of carousels by class

Comment: The code is part of a elementor widget .Elementor is WordPress builder plugin but it is not able to trigger owl carousel by himself. Also i have that console .log in the js function and i see that the function is called the right no of times and with the right id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238644/discussion-between-aleksandr-abramov-and-crerem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem in the hashListener function in the OwlCarousel plugin.
When you create your html and you don't need hash navigation - dont put attributes data-hash="..." to your html markup for carousel items.

Comment: Indeed the problem is having  data-hash in the markup - It does not matter if you have   URLhashListener:false, in the js code